# ERROR on oled + 0.96 display: different mode has already been set!

Tags: display, picamera

I made two programs separately, but when I tried to put them toguether, the following issue came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/CalculadoraDefinitiva/botaoLed.py", line 159, in <module>
    setup()
  File "/home/pi/CalculadoraDefinitiva/botaoLed.py", line 68, in setup
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
ValueError: A different mode has already been set!
```

My program basically consists of a camera capturing images and a display that should show some text.
The problem I believe is somewhere here:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera

# - imports do display
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_SSD1306
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
import subprocess

# - gpio
button = 16
buttontwo = 12
led    = 18

# ------ CONFIGURAÇÃO DO DISPLAY --------

# Raspberry Pi pin configuration:
RST = None     # on the PiOLED this pin isnt used
# Note the following are only used with SPI:
DC = 23
SPI_PORT = 0
SPI_DEVICE = 0

# 128x32 display with hardware I2C:
disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST)

# Initialize library.
disp.begin()

# Clear display.
disp.clear()
disp.display()

# Create blank image for drawing.
# Make sure to create image with mode '1' for 1-bit color.
width = disp.width
height = disp.height
image = Image.new('1', (width, height))

paginacao = 1

# Get drawing object to draw on image.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)

# Draw some shapes.
# First define some constants to allow easy resizing of shapes.
padding = -2
top = padding
bottom = height-padding
# Move left to right keeping track of the current x position for drawing shapes.
x = 0

# Load default font.
font = ImageFont.load_default()

# -----------------------------------------------------

def setup():
       GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
       GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
       GPIO.setup(buttontwo, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
       GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)

def loop():
        while True:
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that the Adafruit library uses a different mode.  A quick glance at the code shows https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/blob/master/Adafruit_GPIO/SPI.py at the root and it has lots of mode configuration.  You will have to work out what mode is being used and change your code to cope.  That may well be as simple as changing the PIN numbers to match the correct mode.